# Find Usage of NamedRange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a number of NamedRanges on my spreadsheet. Aside from UI Find function which can look within formula's;

Is there a GAS/programmatic way to identify if there are usages of NamedRanges and their locations (sheet/cell) ?

Comment: You can retrieve the formulas from a given `Range` and then perform `String` comparisons on those formulas. In your loops over the 2D `Array` of `String`s, you can use the index information to determine the offsets from the top-left of the `Range` you acquired. You'll need to ask a much more specific question to get detailed help / code, or present the code you are working with and identify the errors/issues it is giving you. You can review `Range` methods on the Apps Script API reference, and `String`/`Array` methods on your preferred JavaScript API reference.

Comment: Have you already look at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/?

Comment: @tehhowch Wish I had thunk that - that should work well for me as the range I want to search is also limited (using vertically expanding ArrayFormula's).